# carouselslider 3 images together flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[This is the size of image I want 2 or 3 images to be shown together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXhc3.png)

This is my code :

```
SizedBox(
    width: dW,
    height: dW>800?300:dW>500?200:130,
    child: CarouselSlider(
             items: ['assets/stores1.jpg', 'assets/stores2.jpg', 'assets/stores3.jpg',   'assets/stores4.jpg'].map((item) => Container(
                            width: 500,
                            height: 220,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: dW>500?10:2),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                child: Image.asset(item, fit: BoxFit.fill, width: 500 )
                            ),
                          )
                          ).toList(),
                          carouselController: _controller,
                          options: CarouselOptions(
                            padEnds: false,
                            autoPlay: true,
                          ),
                        )
           ),
```